# Can you recommend IFR material for Europe?

Tags: instrument-flight-rules, instrument-procedures, icao, eu, books

Is there a European equivalent to the FAA's "Instrument Flying Handbook" and "Instrument Procedures Handbook" that will illustrate how to fly different procedures in accordance with ICAO PANS-OPS Doc 8168 and read approach plates (Jeppesen), etc.?